# Why sympy parser does not recognize that some expressions are false?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

In my project i generate dummy strings with logical expresions in form of chain of (non)equalities in form for example:

```
(z > x) & (7 < y) & (x = 2) & (y < x) & (y < z)
```

where operand can be x,y,z or number,  comparationsare in '>=<', always chained as logical end.

Then i use sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr to this strings. If conditions are wrong, it must just return False, like it does for example in case of :

```
('3', '=', 'x'), ('x', '=', '2'), ('5', '<', 'z'), ('9', '>', 'x'), ('x', '<', '9')
```

or

```
('y', '=', '3'), ('y', '=', '9'), ('y', '>', 'x'), ('z', '>', '0'), ('y', '>', 'x')
```

But  some other expressions, are not interpreting like false for example

- (x < x) (simplest one)
- (x < y) & (y < z ) & (z < x) , etc.
  Am i using it somehow wrong and it is possible to calculate is expression false or not, or its a sympy faliule ?

P.S: Also sympy evalues wrong true expressions like :

```
    ('y', '<', 'z'), ('y', '<', 'z'), ('z', '>', 'y'), ('x', '=', 'x'), ('z', '=', 'x')
('x', '<', 'y'), ('z', '=', 'z'), ('x', '<', 'y'), ('x', '=', 'z'), ('8', '>', 'z')
```

its valid, but parser returns False.

Comment: *P.S: Also sympy evalues wrong true expressions*.  `('z', '>', 'y'), ('x', '<', 'y'), ('x', '=', 'z')` should be true ?

Comment: its false, thanks for finding that!!  but another expr is valide and evaluates as false

Answer (score 1):

A copy of a session showing what you passed to the parser would be good, but perhaps this answer will suffice for the more complicated input: something like `(x < x)` does not evaluate because `x` could be anything...and not everything will give False. Some things will raise an error, e.g. `I < I` is neither True nor False, it's an invalid comparison.

If you tell SymPy that `x` is real then the expression will evaluate:

```
>>> var('x',real=True)
x
>>> x<x
False
```

To do so while parsing, pass a "locals" dictionary telling the parser what to use for a given symbol when it is encountered, e.g.

```
>>> parse_expr('x<x',dict(x=symbols('x', real=True)))
False
```

This is not sufficient to resolve `(x < y) & (y < z ) & (z < x)` -- nor is `simplify` yet smart enough to recognize this -- as False:

```
>>> locals = dict(zip('xyz',symbols('x,y,z', real=True)))
>>> parse_expr('(x < y) & (y < z ) & (z < x)', locals).simplify()
(x > z) & (x < y) & (y < z)
```

Comment: i m not familiar with sympy, i use it just for validation here. I do like:
parse_expr('(x<5) & (x == x) & (y>z) & (2>x) & (2<y)'), how to set that x,y,z are real there?

Comment: I updated my previous answer to show a way to make parsed symbols real.